# same calculation functions, different outcomes depending on .load() and .resize() or .scroll()

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, lightbox, css-position

I'm trying to write my own lightbox script but I'm stuck on a problem.

The `wrapper` div centering is done through `position: absolute` and top / left positioned by calculating...

top:

```
_center_vertical = function() {
  return (($(window).height() - wrapper.height()) / 2) - (options.margin + options.border) + $(window).scrollTop()
}
```

left:

```
_center_horizontal = function() {
  return (($(window).width() - wrapper.width()) / 2) - (options.margin + options.border) + $(window).scrollLeft()
}
```

The `wrapper` div is centered on `.load()` and on `$(window).resize()` / `$(window).scroll()`.

When the image is loaded and appended to `wrapper`, top and left is calculated using the functions above, horizontal centering is correct, but vertical centering is not. It is off by around 10px or more.

When the browser window is resized or scrolled, it calls the function which animates the centering which uses the same function to calculate the top and left. The window resize / scroll does center the image properly.

I have tried using jQuery deferred.then() to have it calculate the top / left after the image is appended, but it didn't change anything.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/vfMNQ/

---

I initially thought that the difference in top position changed when I played around with things like wrapper padding (aka my border), however, I found that I was wrong.

I added some `console.log('image load height: ' + ((($(window).height() - wrapper.height()) / 2) - (options.margin + options.border)) + 'px')` to `.load()` and `.scroll()` and found that the difference was oddly 21px no matter what. The default border is 10px, margin is 30... so where did the 21 come from?

I'd hate to use `+ 21` as a hack, but seems like nobody can figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem appears to be in the loading div:

```
    .lbe-loading  {
    background: #578DB2 url(/public/images/loading.gif) no-repeat center center;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    padding: 5px;
    }
```

height:
32 + padding: (5 * 2) = 42

42 / 2 = 21px

Looks like you've appended the image with the loading div still appended to the wrapper.

```
wrapper.append(loading);

...

$(function() {

var img = $(new Image());
img.load(function() {
wrapper.append(this)    // .lbe-loading still appended here 
.css({                  // Position wrapper. 
    ...
});

loading.remove();       // Too late.
```

If I remove .append(loading), it centers fine.

Put .lbe-loading on a different div so it's not being added to the wrapper's height.

Comment: Answer seems most logical. I don't have time to test this out in the next day or so, so you can have the bounty before it expires. Will report back later if it doesn't work or accept as answer.

Answer (score 0):

Best guess:

You are trying to calculate the height of the wrapper before actually putting in the image.

i.e. you are `append(this)` and then immediately trying to calculate the height before giving the browser a chance to display and load the image.

When I put in debugging code `wrapper.height()` changed by 40 pixels after resizing the display. 40 pixels is exactly the border + margin. (And when I changed those, the difference changed too.)

Comment: should i use jquery deferred.then to separate the actions?

Comment: I don't know, I didn't debug it all the way. The fact that's it's off exactly border + margin is suspicious.

Comment: At one time, the difference was the options.border (10px), but when I changed the options.border from 10 to 100, the difference was only 20px which is why I said I couldn't pinpoint the source.

Comment: @gavsiu I'm sorry, I don't know. If I do figure it out I'll post here.

Answer (score 0):

Its a delay in wrapper getting the height and width of the image. The jQuery for centering is executing before Browser has preformed its reflow and given 'wrapper' the height and width of the image.

I forked your fiddle and fixed it here: http://jsfiddle.net/3th5k/
by setting wrapper's height and width with javascript before centering. This way your centering calculation draws from the right data source, the javascript image object rather than the dom.

Also please note that the css statement with 'opacity: 0' has been replaced with .hide(); I did this because opacity and ie are not friends and it would most likely cause a problems down the line.

Cheers!

Comment: It still looks the same on load in Firefox 5. Properly centers after I resize the html section.

Comment: Hmm I justed tested in FF5 and FF3.5 works on load on both more me. Did an update to get rid of my uneeded alert. http://jsfiddle.net/3th5k/1/

Comment: This is what I see in my browser. Firefox 5 says it's up to date. http://imageshack.us/f/163/unled1dg.jpg/

Comment: Looks centered in your picture too. Is there another issue I am unaware of?

Comment: Vertical position is not centered

Comment: Hmmm. I tested it again, and it looks like vertical center onload and vertical center on resize are producing the same results, so it's not my fix but rather your _center_vertical function is miscalculating. But that's another issue all together. This still solves the problem you are posting about, which is that image height and width were not being accounted for onload, but rather on resize alone. I suspect that vertical center is not being accomplished in FF has something to do with settings.border . But like I said, that's another issue.

Comment: You will note that Joe's solution produces the same vertical centering. But while removing other useful code.